# Сохранение объекта в shared_ptr

Tags: c++

Есть у меня такая функция

```cpp
void process(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CMapObject>> & array);
```

В этой функции мне нужно вытащить и сохранить все CMapObject. Делаю так

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<CMapObject> save_obj;  // На самом деле это поле класса
void save(const std::shared_ptr<CMapObject> & obj) {
  save_obj = obj;
}

void process(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CMapObject>> & array) {
    std::for_each(
        array.cbegin(),
        array.cend(),
        [this](const std::unique_ptr<CMapObject> &mapObj) -> void {
            save(mapObj);
        }
    );
}
```

На вызове `save(mapObj);` получаю ошибку

> cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::unique_ptr<CMapObject,std::default_delete>' to 'const std::shared_ptr &'

Аналогичная ошибка при вызове

```cpp
save(std::move(mapObj));
```

А как должно быть? У сохраненного объекта `mapObj` будут вызываться только const методы

Comment: Функция принимает ссылку на `shared_ptr`, а вы пытаетесь передать в нее `unique_ptr`. Это не должно работать. Ну и их смешивание явно говорит о том, что в логике какая-то ошибка.

Comment: @user7860670 вам бы следовало подучить как работают умные указатели.

Comment: `unique_ptr` - в одном экземпляре и только он один может удалить выделенную память под объект. Если он отдаст свой указатель налево, то он потеряет доступ к контролю выделенной памяти. Если эта эксклюзивность вам не нужна, то не пользуйтесь. А если хотите отдать контроль, то уберите константность.

Comment: чтобы вызывать константные методы указатель должен быть таким : `std::shared_ptr<CMapObject` **const** `> save_obj;`

Comment: @user7860670 есть чужой метод, который возвращает вектор из unique_ptr. Мне нужно забрать объекты из этого вектора и сохранить у себя. Где ошибка?

Comment: Если вектор к вам приходит с const квалификатором, то это говорит о том, что владение объектами, которые в нем лежат, передать в shared_ptr нельзя. Вместо этого вам надо либо делать копию объектов, либо сохранять невладеющие ссылки на них (если объекты живут достатончо долго).

Comment: @user7860670 Пожалуй, этого комментария для меня достаточно. Спасибо. Можете сделать из него отдельный ответ

Answer (score -1):

Ненужно const.

```
std::shared_ptr<int> save_obj;  // На самом деле это поле класса
void save(const std::shared_ptr<int> & obj) {
  save_obj = obj;
}

void process(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>& array) {
    std::for_each(
        array.begin(),
        array.end(),
        [](std::unique_ptr<int> &mapObj) -> void {
            save(std::move(mapObj));
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Сильный совет. После такого вектор останется с нулевыми указателями, а все объекты, кроме последнего, будут удалены. Тут проблема же ни столько в вызове подходящего конструктора, сколько в странной логике передачи владения объектами.

Comment: тут бы посмотреть, что на самом деле делает save. Возможно, ему не нужно "сохранять себе объект", тогда код сильно-сильно упрощается

Comment: @KoVadim таки нужно. Потом доступ к сохраненном объекту будет происходить при вызове других методов. Пока не нужно было сохранять на будущее, а использовать по месту было `save(const CMapObject & obj);`

Comment: а если нужно сохранить, то либо делать копию, либо не использовать unique_ptr.

Comment: @KoVadim `unique_ptr` - это стороннее SDK. Тут от него не уйдешь. Как копию делать?

Comment: Надо смотреть. Не всякий класс можно так просто взять и скопировать. Если внутри лежит std::ifstream...  Но у unique_ptr есть функция get, которая возвращает голый указатель на внутренние данные. Разыменовывайте го и вперед. Но это может сломать логику Вашей программы. Или сохраняйте этот указатель (но это тоже страшно)

Comment: @KoVadim так этот же указатель погибнет при выходе вектора из зоны видимости

Comment: а я о чем же! Но может сохранить весь вектор себе?

Comment: @KoVadim идея: получить вектор объектов, создать над каждым объектом оболочку и вернуть дальше уже вектор оболочек. Негде его сохранять. Похоже придется таки через `std::move` подчищать вектор и забирать указатели себе. Это не противоречит логике, но нужно не забыть, что после вызова `process()` вектор будет пустой